# TextView with data from firebase rt dababase disappear on screen

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get a user name from the database and set it as text on the screen.
I have 3 Activity and Fragment objects.

The first activity is `RegisterActivity`. After the user inserts his email and password, and clicks the *next* button, a pop up with input fields for user details  appears.

Users should fill all fields and click the save button.
For the `OnClick` action of the save button, all users details are written to a real time database.

In the main Activity, I want to show the user *name* from the database.
In debug mode, I get the user *name*, but it won't show on the `TextView` (`private TextView mWelcomeText`).

Here is what I've done:

```
package com.enjoyapp.weddapp.Activities;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextView mWelcomeText;
    private String mGreetings;
    private String mDisplayName;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase db;
    private DatabaseReference users;

    private MethodManager mm;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = db.getReference("Users");

        mWelcomeText = findViewById(R.id.mWelcomeText);
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);


        getDataFromUsersDetails();

        mWelcomeText.setText(mDisplayName);


        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_favorites:
                            selectedFragment = new FavoritesFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_search:
                            selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment)
                            .commit();
                    return true;
                }
            };

    public void getDataFromUsersDetails() {
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    mDisplayName = ds.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("mEventOwnerName").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("Database reader", mDisplayName);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };
        users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }

    public String getGreetings() {
        mm = new MethodManager();

        if (mm.getTime() >= 6 && mm.getTime() < 12) {
            return "Good morning";
        } else if (mm.getTime() >= 12 && mm.getTime() < 18) {
            return "Good afternoon";
        } else if (mm.getTime() >= 18 && mm.getTime() < 22) {
            return "Good evening";
        } else if (mm.getTime() >= 22 && mm.getTime() < 6) {
            return "Good night";
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I want the text to be displayed on the screen, in the field of `private TextView mWelcomeText`.

In the `layout_main` I can see the text view with the tool:`text="something";`
But when I am running it on a real device or an emulator, just an empty place appears.
UPDATE:

```
public void getDataFromUsersDetails() {
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                mDisplayName = ds.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("mEventOwnerName").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("Database reader", mDisplayName);
                user = new User();
                user.setmDisplayName(mDisplayName);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
    users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

mWelcomeText = findViewById(R.id.mWelcomeText);

```
    mWelcomeText.setText(user.setGreetingsOnTop());

public String setGreetingsOnTop(){
    MethodManager mm = new MethodManager();
    String greetings = null;

    if (mm.getTime() >= 6 && mm.getTime() < 12) {
        greetings = "Good morning";
    } else if (mm.getTime() >= 12 && mm.getTime() < 18) {
        greetings = "Good afternoon";
    } else if (mm.getTime() >= 18 && mm.getTime() < 22) {
        greetings = "Good evening";
    } else if (mm.getTime() >= 22 && mm.getTime() < 6) {
        greetings = "Good night";
    }
    return getmDisplayName() +""+greetings;
}
```

Comment: Please post the database structure. `android:text=""` It is hardcoded value set to the textView.

Comment: mWelcomeText.setText(mDisplayName); move this line inside for loop of getDataFromUsersDetails.

Comment: Please place you database structure edit your question, Have you check your log if the name is not null?

Answer (score 0):

I would request you take a look on this two line of Main Activity.

```
    getDataFromUsersDetails();

    mWelcomeText.setText(mDisplayName); //mDisplayName is null initially
```

getDataFromUsersDetails is making an asynchronous call using valueEventListener. When the response is coming you are assigning the value to mDisplayName but it will not update in textView.

In the For loop you need to explicitly update `mWelcomeText.setText(mDisplayName);`

Comment: Hey, it worked very well for me, thank you very much.
Now I slightly changed the code, I added splash activity in which I bring the data from the firebase database before main activity started (otherwise it takes about 3 seconds until the text (mWelcomeText.setText(mDisplayName)) is displayed).
In splash activity, a added the function (getDataFromUsersDetails()). And in the function, instead of doing setText I create a user object and do setText(mDisplayName).
After that in main activity I do user.getText and get null.
know why ? a new code in the main quastion

Comment: Your Code is not in readable format. You are mixing the code of different activity. Add new question instead for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904790/textview-with-data-from-firebase-rt-dababase-disappear-on-screen-2nd-qustion

Answer (score 0):

You can must update the textview inside the valueEventListener

```
 for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                mDisplayName = ds.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("mEventOwnerName").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("Database reader", mDisplayName);
                mWelcomeText.setText(mDisplayName);//here
            }
```