# TextView with data from firebase rt dababase disappear on screen - 2nd qustion

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get a user name from the database and set it as text on the screen. I have 3 Activity and Fragment objects.

I'm trying to get name of the user in main activity:

The first activity is a login activity that have user sign in and sign up functions with firebase auth integration.

After that , if sign in or sign up success , Splash activity is open.
in splash activity , i should get user display name ().

In the () function i'm creating a new user object and setting the display name.

after 3 seconds , Splash activity is closed and main activity is open.
in main activity i'm calling to user.getDisplayName.

Splash activity:

```
public void getDataFromUsersDetails() {
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    mDisplayName = ds.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("mEventOwnerName").getValue(String.class);
                    user = new User();
                    user.setmDisplayName(mDisplayName);
                }
            }
        users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }
User class:
public String setGreetingsOnTop(){
        return getmDisplayName();
    }
MainActivity:
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        user = new User();


        mWelcomeText = findViewById(R.id.mWelcomeText);
        mWelcomeText.setText(user.getmDisplayName());
        mWelcomeText.setText(user.setGreetingsOnTop());
    }
```

I want the text to be displayed on the screen, in the field of private TextView mWelcomeText.

In the layout_main I can see the text view with the tool:text="something"; But when I am running it on a real device or an emulator, just an empty place appears.

Comment: You can check a **[repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp-Clean-Architecture-MVVM/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebaseapp)** of mine where I have successfully implemented Firebase auth together with a login and splash activity.

Comment: Thanks , but it's not what i need.

Comment: Please take a look at the docs about design-time attributes - https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html#tools_instead_of_android

Comment: And next time please ask 2 separate questions instead of one.

Comment: @VadimKotov You probably didn't understand the question, suggest you read again =]